# 000webhost SMTP Error: Could not authenticate Error in PhpMailer

Tags: php, email, smtp, gmail

I am developing an android application, I am doing below things for forgot password.

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;

//sender address
$name = "name";
$email = "emailaddress@gmail.com";


require_once  "PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php";
require_once  "PHPMailer/SMTP.php";
require_once  "PHPMailer/Exception.php";
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

function sendMail($password){
    global $mail,$email,$name;
    $response = array();

    try{
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->Username="myemail@gmail.com";
        $mail->Password="myemailpassword";
        $mail->Port=465;
        $mail->SMTPSecure="ssl";

        $mail->isHtML(true);
        $mail->setFrom($email,$name);
        $mail->addAddress("friendemail@gmail.com","friendname");
        $mail->Subject = ("FORGOT PASSWORD");
        $mail->Body="THIS IS BODY";

        $res = $mail->send();
        $response['error'] = false;
        $response['message'] = "Password sent to your Email id ....";
    }
    catch(Exception $e){
        $response['error'] = true;
        $response['message'] = $mail->ErrorInfo;
        
    
    }
return $response;
}
?>
```

I hosted my database and files in `00webhost`free web hosting platform [link](https://in.000webhost.com/)
And I am using `postman` tool to check the response

**If I run same file in localhost, it will send the email**

Even I tried with enabling the *Less secure app access* in gmail account.

But I still not able to send mail using OOOwebhost.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: [How to use PHPMailer 000webhost forum](https://www.000webhost.com/forum/t/how-to-use-phpmailer/134686)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP mail function doesn't complete sending of e-mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644436/php-mail-function-doesnt-complete-sending-of-e-mail)

Comment: Free hosting services are generally worth less than you paid for them.

Comment: @SimoneRossaini yes it worked form me thanks

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular thank you also, your valuable information